# Set the padding of an element using other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the padding of ten divs using javascript. The divs are used to create a border around the centered main text which changes color, so I can't use box shadows and flex box(already tried it). I am doing this so it works well responsively. This is how I set it up in html:

`<span id="title-text" class="head-text center">Tudor Popescu</span>
    <div id="[one - ten]" class="center border-ring"></div>`

The equation I am using to set the padding of each 'border-ring' is:

N = ring number

CW = content width (text width)

CH = content height(text height)

B = border width

W = window height

W = window width

`side padding = N(((0.5 * W) - (0.5 * CW) - (10 * B)) / 11)`

`vertical padding = N(((0.5 * H) - (0.5 * CH) - (10 * B)) / 11)`

What I tried already: 
I tried using jQuery so it is easier to work with. I only tried with one div to make sure it works:

```
var totalWidth = $(window).width(),
  totalHeight = $(window).height();

var hOne = ((0.5 * totalHeight) - (0.5 * $('#title-text').height()) - (10 * 
document.getElementsByClassName('border-ring')[0].style.borderWidth) / 11);
var wOne = ((0.5 * totalWidth) - (0.5 * $('#title-text').width()) - (10 * 
document.getElementsByClassName('border-ring')[0].style.borderWidth) / 11);
hOne = hOne.toString();
wOne = wOne.toString();

document.getElementById('one').style.padding = `${hOne}px ${wOne}px 
${hOne}px ${wOne}px`;
```

I would like to know how to do this properly and how to make the code work as right now the padding are bigger than the view port of the website.

Comment: What's your question? Is something not working, or not working the way you expect?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The code is not working and I wan to find out how to do it properly.

Comment: Not working how? What are you expecting to see, and what are you seeing instead? How do you run the code you've shown? Do you get any errors? (BTW, it may help you to get answers if you [demonstrate the problem](/help/mcve) with a runnable example; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The code doesn't work in the sense that the way I expressed the equation doesn't add the desired padding. They are set to the default which is 0px.

Comment: The string you have in the last line of code is not going to replace the variable names with their values. For that you must use the backquotes (template literal) instead of normal quotes. Did you not think of debugging and inspecting the actual value assigned to `style.padding`?

Comment: @trincot thanks for that, I forgot. But now, the border seems to be bigger than the screen itself. Also, I have tried debugging it by seeing the value of it, I thought something inside the equation was wrong as I am quite new to javascript.

Comment: But why don't you just `console.log(..)` each of the intermediate values as you build up the final expression and see where the values are not as expected, and focus on that? what do you get for `totalHeight`, `totalWidth`, `document.getElementsByClassName('border-ring')[0].style.borderWidth`, ...etc, etc. This is something you really need to do, and then tell us exactly which value is not as it should be.

Comment: @trincot - Or rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, Tudor could *turn on the lights* using the debugger built into his/her browser. :-)

Comment: Yes, that would be better. But then its often like opening pandora's box: *"How do I use the debugger?"* ... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried using the debugger but when logging, the value doesn't show up and tells me to go to another location, normally the index.html, and yes I'm not that experienced in web development yet :p